# URL Rewriting in IIS 6 Using ISAPI_Rewrite 3

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

I am running into an issue where I am trying to implement SEO friendly links in an ASP.Net 3.5 application with IIS6.  The issue is that when I try to use a url like "www.text.com/about/" it isn't directed to the ASP.Net pipeline, so I am unable to route the request to the correct physical aspx file.  With ISAPI_Rewrite I know I can redirect a request to the specific page, but is there a way to have a request sent to the ASP.Net pipeline, so I can manipulate the request using the built-in routing engine.  Any help is appreciated.

Wade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the technet article on how to route wildcard traffic to the asp.net pipeline.  Here is the link - http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/5c5ae5e0-f4f9-44b0-a743-f4c3a5ff68ec.mspx?mfr=true.

Answer (score 0):

Wade ,

You can either implement urlmodule which extents ihttpmodule.

or you can implement httphandler , You need to make this entry in httphandler section of web.config , so that each request comes to .net handler , you can customize your path there and rewrite the url

let me know if you need any help.

as sample example

http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/advanced/httphandler-aspnet2-csharp.aspx

let me know if you need any help , i implemented recently